# prove that norm 1 of a function is less than or equal to (b-a) infinity norm of that function where X=C[a,b]

Tags: normed-spaces

Prove that norm 1 of a function is less than or equal to (b-a) infinity norm of that function where  X=C[a,b] is the continuous space function f:[a,b] to R.

norm 1 is defined to be ntegral of the functionand nfinity norm is supremum of absolute value of that function

but how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$|f(x)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Now use monotonicity of the integral.